# Using ruby with databases, but without rails

Tags: sql, ruby, database, database-connection

I've some huge text files to process and make sense out of the data.  Part of the task is to save this data into a database.  I want to use Ruby, with postgres or mysql, postgres being the first choice.  What libraries should I include?  There is no model, its going to be plain SQL statements.  How to do this without rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, you want [ruby-pg](http://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home). It supplies your basic database connection with the ability to query it. The documentation is sparse, but there are plenty of code samples in the source tree. Here's a fairly straightforward one:

https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/e4465a9779faed39825213d140df6b1531bb1e68/spec/pg/result_spec.rb?at=default

Edit: The MySQL site lists a few options for connecting to MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ruby.html

Comment: The link is dead, do you have an alternative?

Comment: @JohnMerlino They appear to have changed their tests around. But I updated the link to a comparable example.

Answer (score 4):

Sequel - sequel.rubyforge.org - is great as well. Using the core library (not the Sequel::Model ORM) you can write SQL like queries/statements using Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're after [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), which supplies the database connectivity. A quick google search suggested [this](http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Nope, I dont want to use ORM (activerecord is ORM, right?) I want to write my own SQL statements, like the way we do with mysql_query, mysql_connect etc in PHP.

Comment: Yes, ActiveRecord is an ORM, and is overkill for executing plain SQL statements.

Comment: still and orm but its light and faaast http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html - datamapper. its also easy to use outside rails

Answer (score 0):

for mysql, check out the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem

```
#>> gem install mysql2
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
```